# Why is the desired attribute not being added to the variable?

Tags: javascript, css, styling

**I don't get why the attributes are not being set to the variable**
**Why is the colour not changing?**

Here is the code :

```js
var text = document.createElement('h2');
text.textContent = 'TEXT';
text.setAttribute("style", "color: red, margin-top:5px");
document.body.appendChild(text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `color: red, margin-top:5px` to `color: red; margin-top:5px`

```js
var text = document.createElement('h2');
text.textContent = 'TEXT';
text.setAttribute("style", "color: red; margin-top:5px");
document.body.appendChild(text);
```